# Switch from Parallel to Ubuntu only

Tags: hard-drive, parallels

I'm currently running Ubuntu in parallel with Windows 7.  I'm tired of Windows 7.  I have all my files on an external hard drive and my plan was to just move them to the Ubuntu partition, but apparently there's limited space on the parallel version of Ubuntu...?  Is that right?  If so, what do I need to do to trash Windows and start from scratch?

Comment: Look for oldfred's input in this post >> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2136338

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have windows and ubuntu installed in your PC.
Now, you want to move to ubuntu completely.

If you have already **backed up** your important files to external hard disk, you can simply increase the size of ubuntu partition by Gparted.

If your ubuntu partition is **NOT** the first partion, then you will have to reinstall Ubuntu, by formatting and using new partition for the whole hard disk

For more information on GPARTED, check http://gparted.org/